# Consider a set $U$ of $23$ different compounds in a chemistry lab

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider a set $U$ of $23$ different compounds in a chemistry lab. There is a subset $S$ of $U$ of $9$ compounds, each of which reacts with exactly $3$ compounds of $U$. Consider the following statements:

a. Each compound in $U \setminus S$ reacts with an odd number of compounds.

b. At least one compound in $U \setminus S$ reacts with an odd number of compounds.

c. Each compound in $U \setminus S$ reacts with an even number of compounds.

Which one of the above statements is ALWAYS TRUE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this as a graph problem with $23$ vertices corresponding to $23$ different compounds. Whenever a compound reacts with other, we have an edge in between them. So, according to the question, we have $9$ vertices with exactly $3$ edges. Therefore, total degree of these $9$ vertices (subset S) is $27$ which is odd. However, we know that total degree of a graph is always even, because each edge contributes degree $2$. Therefore, total degree of the vertices in $U \setminus S$ must be odd to make the total degree of $U$ even.

---

Now, **Statement I is not always true**, because to make the total degree of $U \setminus S$ odd, each vertex of $U \setminus S$ don't need to have odd degree; only one vertex in $U \setminus S$ having odd degree is enough which makes **Statement II always true**. If all the vertices in $U \setminus S$ have even degrees, then the total degree of $U \setminus S$ cannot be odd. So, **Statement III is always false**. Hope it helps.